# Sinatra request["SOME_HEADER"] doesn't work on POST; doc bug?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

The Sinatra README [says](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object):

```
request["SOME_HEADER"]      # value of SOME_HEADER header
```

Given this app:

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/env' do
    env['HTTP_X_FOO']
end

post '/request' do 
    request['X-Foo']
end

post '/request_rack_http_format' do
    request['HTTP_X_FOO']
end
```

The first spec passes; the next two fail:

```
describe "Sinatra should place the header in" do
    before(:all) do
        header 'X-Foo', 'Bar'
    end

    example "env" do
        post '/env'
        last_response.body.should == 'Bar' #pass
    end

    example "request[]" do
        post '/request'
        last_response.body.should == 'Bar' #fail; got ""
    end

    example "request[] (rack format)" do
        post '/request_rack_http_format'
        last_response.body.should == 'Bar' #fail; got ""
    end
end
```

Looking at the source, Sinatra doesn't actually do anything with `[]`; it's implemented in Rack as the union of `GET` and `POST`. And `POST` [just returns the form hash](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L194). For `GET` it's the query hash. In all three routes, `request.params` is empty.

**My question:** Is this a doc bug, or am I misunderstanding how to use `request[]`? For now, my application is working fine with the `env[]` method. But I want to do it "right."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the documentation. `request[]` actually retrieves the params for the request, not the header:

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L262

```
def [](key)
  params[key.to_s]
end
```

I double checked it by testing also. Seems a bit silly, but it looks like you really can't directly access the header in any way **except through `env`**. At least I could not figure out any other way.

Comment: I'm thinking you're right since [the Rack source itself seems to use `env`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L308)

Comment: I just [opened an issue with Sinatra for the README](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/542).

Answer (score 7):

I realized that if a param in header is 'SOME_HEADER'

I can access it with

```
env['HTTP_SOME_HEADER']
```

so Sinatra (maybe Rack) seems to add the **HTTP_** prefix (and uppercasing)... 
strange.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as Giorgio said the header was capitalized and formatted like so:

```
env['HTTP_SOME_HEADER']
```

with any hyphens converted to underscores. Which is pretty confusing.